# Devolver posiciones aleatorias de un arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una función que recibe un ArrayList(tamaño 15) y necesito devolver 8 posiciones aleatorias sin que se repitan los elementos que hay dentro. Cómo podría hacerlo?Dejo el código abajo por si sirve de guía, gracias de antemano.

```
public static ArrayList<Equipo> getEquiposOeste() {
        Statement smt = utilsDB.conectarBBDD();

        ArrayList<Equipo> ret = new ArrayList<Equipo>();

        try {
            ResultSet cursor = smt.executeQuery("select * from equipo where conferencia=2 ");
            while (cursor.next()) {
                Equipo actual = new Equipo();

                actual.setEq_id(cursor.getByte("eq_id"));
                actual.setNombre(cursor.getString("nombre"));
                actual.setCiudadLocal(cursor.getString("ciudadlocal"));
                actual.setGM(cursor.getString("gm"));
                actual.setLimiteSalarial(cursor.getFloat("limitesalarial"));
                actual.setPropietario(cursor.getString("propietario"));
                actual.setConferencia_id(cursor.getByte("conferencia"));

                ret.add(actual);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        utilsDB.desconectarBBDD();
        return ret;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Equipo> devolverPrimeraRondaEste() {
        ArrayList<Equipo> ret = FuncionesUtiles.getEquiposEste();
        
        

        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera rapida de obtener numeros aleatoreos limitados sin repetirse es usando el metodo[ints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) de la clase Random seguido de [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)el cual devuelve un flujo que consta de los distintos elementos.

```
//Array de 15 elementos indices (0-14)
int limite=nombreDelArray.size()-1;
int [] indicesAleatorios=new Random().ints(0,limite).distinct().limit(8).toArray();
```

Comment: Buenas,he probado el método de vez en cuando se me repite una posición de vez en cuando,sabrias arreglarlo?.Gracias

Comment: dentro del array obtenido los 8 números serán al azar del 0-14 sin repetirse ,lo mas probable es que al agregando los equipos estés obviando algo, te comparto un ejemplo [codigo](https://paiza.io/projects/e/L1pHj7yf_MAXuSXlSE0x6A) ,espero  aclare un poco mas la respuesta que aporte

Answer (score 1):

Dado un ArrayList de equipos (`ArrayList<Equipo>`), para obtener 8 elementos de manera aleatorias puedes:

1. Copiar el Array Original:

```java
// equipos es el arrayList de equipos de los 15 equipos
ArrayList<Equipo> equiposAleatorios = new ArrayList<>(equipos);
```

2. Aleatorizar el array copiado:

```java
Collections.shuffle(equiposAleatorios);
```

3. Seleccionar los primeros 8 elementos del array aleatorizado:

```java
equiposAleatorios = equiposAleatorios.stream()
                    .limit(8)
                    .collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ));
```

Finalmente, la variable `equiposAleatorios` tendrá 8 elementos aleatorios de la lista original. Te adjunto el código íntegró a continuación. Puedes ejecutar un ejemplo online [en este enlace](https://onlinegdb.com/qYCj-S8lB).

```java
ArrayList<Equipo> equiposAleatorios = new ArrayList<>(equipos);
Collections.shuffle( equiposAleatorios );
equiposAleatorios = equiposAleatorios.stream()
                    .limit( 8 )
                    .collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma posible es filtrando la lista:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) 
    {
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * tuArray);

        System.out.println("posiciones random :" + tuArray.get(index));
    }
```

Comment: Buenas,he probado el método y se me ha repetido una posición 3 veces así que no me sirve,gracias igualmente